# search for substring allowing dashes python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

Does anybody know how I can search for a substring allowing dashes between the characters?

Something like that.

```
AAABBC
AA---A--BB-C
```

I would like the above substring to match the one below.

Any response is apreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add `-*` in-between those characters.

```
r'A-*A-*A-*B-*B-*C'
```

Example:

```
>>> re.match(r'^A-*A-*A-*B-*B-*C$', 'AA---A--BB-C')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 12), match='AA---A--BB-C'>
>>> re.match(r'^A-*A-*A-*B-*B-*C$', 'A----AA--BB-C')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='A----AA--BB-C'>
>>> re.match(r'^A-*A-*A-*B-*B-*C$', 'A--A-A--B-B-C')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 13), match='A--A-A--B-B-C'>
```